# EntityFramework Core MySQL Script-Migration export customization

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I run `Script-Migration` in my project that uses EntityFramework Core 2 and MySql, it produces the right set of statements but out of 200 statements, only 5 missing ending semicolon. I already found solutions to override `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator` configuration in EntityFramework 6 in the following link:[EF6 MySql: Update-Database -Script generates SQL without semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781748/ef6-mysql-update-database-script-generates-sql-without-semicolon) , I was wondering about the EF core implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF core implementation is similar with some difference in overriding `Generate` method, here is the implementation for `CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
namespace test
{
/// <summary>
/// Custom MigrationSqlGenerator to add semi-colons to the end of 
/// all migration statements.
/// </summary>
public class CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator : MySqlMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    private readonly MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies _dependencies;

    public CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator(MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies, 
        IMigrationsAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations, 
        IMySqlOptions options): base(dependencies, migrationsAnnotations, options)
    {
        _dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public override IReadOnlyList<MigrationCommand> Generate(IReadOnlyList<MigrationOperation> operations, IModel model = null)
    {
        List<MigrationCommand> result = new List<MigrationCommand>();
        IEnumerable<MigrationCommand> statements = base.Generate(operations, model);
        foreach (MigrationCommand statement in statements)
        {
            var factory = _dependencies.CommandBuilderFactory.Create();
            factory.Append((statement.CommandText.TrimEnd() + ";").Replace(";;", ";"));
            result.Add(new MigrationCommand(factory.Build(), statement.TransactionSuppressed));
        }
        return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Also you need to set the configuration in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator>();
    }
```

Comment: I have tested this code with Entity Framework Core 5.0.5 and Pomelo.EntityFramework.MySql 5.0.0 but I got this error when I executed “Script-Migration -context MyDbContext --idempotent”: Unable to resolve service for type 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.Internal.IMySqlOptions' while attempting to activate 'MT4.WebManager.API.HelperClasses.CustomMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator'. Would you help me?